# Hide "invoice #" in the invoice PDF

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

How can I hide the text "invoice #........" in the invoice PDF document?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the invoice layout by modifying this file : `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice
(app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php)`

Copy it over on this location to override it.

```
app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
```

and try to comment this line

```
$page->drawText(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId(), 35, 780, 'UTF-8');
```

Some more information

- http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-magento-pdf-invoice-and-packingslip/
- http://www.satollo.net/magento-how-to-sligtly-modify-the-invoice-pdf
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/custom-pdf-templates/
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/orders/editing_an_invoice_pdf

Comment: Your method works, thank you! And if I also want to translate the invoice, which file have I to modify? @St0iK